# Synonyms and Merges

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Now that you have pro tem mods, you may want to think of organizing your tags. One step is merging tags that aren't really different in that they apply to the same posts.

You can see some proposed synonyms here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms , and you can always propose more if you have the rep/score, but it's usually easier to discuss on meta and let the mods run a tag merge+synonym (which is usually better than a plain synonym)

---

For one, the tag [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) has lots of tags that ought to be merged into it. [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal), [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram), [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin), [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not), and [islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules). Giving a post which already has [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia), one of these tags doesn't add much to the question.

Comment: see also http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/72 and http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/149