# Let's not have an "Is X halal?" tag?

Tags: discussion, tag, burninate-request

### *Proposal*: Let's not have an "*Is X halal?*" tag.

**TL;DR**: As a solution to the [halal/haram family of tags](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1844/17163) problem, I (tentatively) propose we burninate/blacklist all of the tags: [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal), [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram), [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram), [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal), [halal-consumer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-consumer), [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin), [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not), [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling).

It's a big change, so it needs careful thought, so I post this for voting and feedback.  I do some "sanity checks" below, which has increased my confidence in this possibility.

### *Justification*

1. **Tags should indicate what a question is *about*.**  Questions like *Is X halal?* or *Is X permissible?* are about X, and should be tagged [x](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x).  Questions that are actually about "halal" or "sin" can instead be tagged [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) and [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh).
2. **It feels like a meta tag** for two reasons, both listed on [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), Jeff Atwood, 2010:

   1. > If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags ... tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

      A question tagged [is-x-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/is-x-halal) (or some variant) still needs to be tagged [x](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x).
   2. > The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like ... what “kind” of question it is
3. **The title of the question should contain something equivalent to "Is X halal?"** How this would work:

   1. Title: [Sharing videos in website is halal or haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32773/17163) can be tagged [internet](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) (and maybe we need a [video](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) tag too).
   2. Title: [Is arbitrage betting haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31445/17163) can be tagged [gambling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gambling)
   3. Title: [Are video games permissible?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31309/17163) can be tagged [software](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software)
   4. Title: [Is it halal to be a makeup artist?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31207/17163) can be tagged [work](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work) [cosmetics](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmetics)
4. **The [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) tag is a [compound tag](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2939/17163)**, i.e., is has the form [x-y](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-y) where [x](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x) and [y](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y) are also tags.

   Compound tags are going to lead to confusion as to which of the three tags [x-y](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-y), [x](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x), and [y](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y) to use.  Users might simply pick some random subset of the three.  (In the [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal) case, we also have [y-x](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y-x) too!)
5. **It's impractical.**  These tags desperately need work, and once we get them working, they will require maintenance.  If this is not done, they'll just remain (or return to) being a big and accumulating mess.
6. **There's minor differences in phrasing** which perhaps led to the many variants of the tag:

   1. *Is X halal?* E.g. [Is selling virtual weapon skins haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37497/17163)
   2. *Is X permissible?* E.g. [Is it permissible for a girl to reject a proposal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38270/17163)
   3. *Is X a sin?* E.g. [Is it a sin to accept e.g. food from a relative who supports herself using riba?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36799/17163)
   4. *What is the ruling concerning X?* E.g. [What is ruling for Blasphemy in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36928/17163)

### *Sanity check 1: random questions can be re-tagged [pass]*

Here's 5 randomly generated questions generated by [DiceStack](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack) for various tags:

- [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram):

  1. [Can a muslim cook pig meat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10719/can-a-muslim-cook-pig-meat) can be tagged [pork](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pork) [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) and we could create a [cooking](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking) if desired
  2. [Working in Club as a waiter is haram or halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17959/working-in-club-as-a-waiter-is-haram-or-halal) can be tagged [work](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work) [alcohol](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol) [gambling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gambling)
  3. [Is getting unauthorized discounts on store products haraam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25957/is-getting-unauthorized-discounts-on-store-products-haraam) seems fine tagged [theft](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theft), but maybe something like (not yet existent) [shopping](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping) might also be useful
  4. [Does food need a halal certification?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8318/does-food-need-a-halal-certification) seems fine tagged [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food), but might be better off with the (not yet existent) [halal-certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-certification) or [dietry-laws](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dietry-laws)
  5. [Is this allowed to bribe when I am forced?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/is-this-allowed-to-bribe-when-i-am-forced) should have a useful tag created, e.g., [bribery](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bribery)
- [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal):

  1. [Is it permissible to eat meat in Western restaurants given that it is permissible to eat meat from People of the Book?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37384/is-it-permissible-to-eat-meat-in-western-restaurants-given-that-it-is-permissibl) seems fine with [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) and [meat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meat); it might benefit from [non-muslim-countries](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-muslim-countries) (actually, I just went ahead and edited the tags)
  2. [Is there a concept of "nullification" of forbidden substances in Halal dietary laws?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21624/is-there-a-concept-of-nullification-of-forbidden-substances-in-halal-dietary-l) has the useful tags [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) and [judaism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism), could benefit from [comparative-religions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-religions) and the (not yet existent) [dietry-laws](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dietry-laws)
  3. [Is making of artificial juices allowed in Islam and drink these juices are halaal or not?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26048/is-making-of-artificial-juices-allowed-in-islam-and-drink-these-juices-are-halaa) currently has the tags [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal); it should be tagged [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) and the (not yet existent) [dietry-laws](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dietry-laws)
  4. [Solutions to Ribaa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35373/solutions-to-ribaa) seems adequately tagged [riba](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riba) and [mortgage](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortgage)
  5. [Absent Father Refuses Marriage Proposal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/absent-father-refuses-marriage-proposal) can be tagged [nikah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nikah) and maybe also [wali](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wali) [parents](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parents)
- [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling):

  1. [Are monthly payments an Islamically acceptable way to receive money for your goods?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/are-monthly-payments-an-islamically-acceptable-way-to-receive-money-for-your-goo) is fine tagged [finance](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance), would benefit from [business](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business), and it looks like it's after a [sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunni) opinion
  2. [Alcohol in perfumes?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/alcohol-in-perfumes) could use the obvious tag [alcohol](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol) and the (not yet existing) [perfume](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perfume).
  3. [Is there philosophical reason for unclean things (nejasat) in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/is-there-philosophical-reason-for-unclean-things-nejasat-in-islam) is fine tagged [islamic-philosophy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-philosophy) [taharah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taharah) [najis](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/najis)
  4. [What is difference of Hadd and Qisas?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10402/what-is-difference-of-hadd-and-qisas) could be tagged [hadd](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hadd) [punishment](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punishment) and (the not yet existent) [qisas](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qisas) and maybe one of [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) and [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh)
  5. [If a non-muslim curses a muslim, will the muslim's life be in turmoil?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37524/if-a-non-muslim-curses-a-muslim-will-the-muslims-life-be-in-turmoil) it seems [curse](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curse) is sufficient.

In these examples, it seems possible to give adequate tags without using an "Is X halal?" tag.

### *Sanity check 2: meets meta.SE criteria [somewhat]*

From the top answer (by [Shog9 ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/351283)) to meta.StackExchange question [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/351283):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?  **Virtually no** and **No!!!** (E.g. using [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram), etc., was defined here [When to use haram and halal-haram tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1126/17163), but not used like that)
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?  **Yes.**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?  **Not really**, the question is (or should be) part of the title.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?  **Yes.**

and also

> Sometimes, tags get in the way, add confusion, start fights, take the place of better tags... -- [Shog9 ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/351283)

These tags seem to be getting in the way more than helping.

### *Sanity check 3: correspondence with low quality questions [slightly]*

> Bad tags are often harbingers of bad questions. -- [Shog9 ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/351283)

I suppose the logic is "effortless tags" correspond to "effortless questions".  Here's some data:

```
tag            % Q's with
               score >= 3

sin               47%
fiqh              47%
sharia            45%
sin-or-not        43%
halal-haram       37%
islamic-ruling    35%
haram             34%
halal-consumer    32%
halal             29%
haram-halal       26%

history           50%
jamaat            49%
women             46%
food              41%
nikah             39%
```

There seems to be some trend there, but not that strong (maybe they were deleted though; or perhaps this is more about poorly written questions).  Nevertheless, there's examples of bad questions searching for [`[halal-haram] score:0 is:question`](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhalal-haram%5D%20score%3A0%20is%3Aquestion).  (I just downvoted a whole bunch of these; they should be automatically deleted.)

### Prior meta posts

- [When to use haram and halal-haram tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1126/17163)
- [How should we tidy up the halal/haram family of tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1844/17163)
- [Tags related to Halal-Haram should be merged](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1905/17163)

and also

- [Removing some tags](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/72/17163)
- [List of tag synonyms and tags to be burninated or removed](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/149/17163)
- [Synonyms and Merges](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/321/17163)